# Activiti Designer Integrate in Spring Java

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, activiti, bpmn

I'm new in Activiti and I have some questions.

My project is developed in java With Spring , and I installed the Activiti Designer .

I drew a process in designer, with service task, and I implements a class that implements JavaDelegate. The problem is that doesn't worked and this doesn't give error.

I don't installed a Activiti database. Does it important or mandatory?

Someone help me , or someone recommended a very good tutorial .

Comment: The activiti.org is the best user guide. You can use ur mysql database itself. Dont need to go for activiti database h2 db

Answer (score 0):

I am also very new to this, but what I have learned till now:

The activity database is the place which Activiti uses for saving processes/process variables etc.
Other than this, it does save the models created for activiti designer. You need to finally deploy these to actually make them start working.

You installed Activiti Designer in eclipse or installed standalone application of designer or installed the activiti-explorer/rest applications?

You need to have Activiti engine with your application to actually use activiti.